# Is there any rss reporter for maven site plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I use maven site plugin to generate site for my product. Is there any ability to generate rss stream to notify users about new versions and new pages on the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[maven-news-plugin](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-news-plugin/) should be able to generate RSS stream for your Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea.

My solution is to use [Nexus professional to deploy Maven sites](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/sites-sect-intro.html). Nexus has a number of [system feeds](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-feeds.html) that publish changes.

Comment: I use github static pages to publish my site, so I think that for now I can just create rss.xml in site resources and add news there each time something changed. Rss format is pretty simple to edit it in any xml editor. But automation of rss editing would be ideal.